# How to make Spring Batch application to use different database for metadata tables in Spring Batch v5.x?

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-batch

I am currently working on a batch application which is built on latest version **(i.e. 5.x)** of spring batch. It is currently using MySQL database for batch data and also metadata. I want the application to use let's say H2 database for metadata and MySQL for batch data.

Since `@EnableBatchProcessing` is discouraged. Not able to find a proper way to handle different datasources

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Boot, you can annotate the datasource you want to use for Spring Batch's meta-data with `@BatchDataSource`.

If you do not use Spring Boot, you can tell Spring Batch which datasource bean to use for the job repository with `@EnableBatchProcessing(dataSource="batchDataSource")`.